# Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing Plugin: add custom text before price

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using the woocommerce Dynamic Pricing Plugin - how can I change the "FROM" field and replace with custom text?

Here's my code which is attempting to filter the [original plugins code](http://pastebin.com/nviw43hQ);

The TEST text works fine, but the price is returning as 0.00

```
add_filter( 'wc_dynamic_pricing_price_html', 'custom_single_price');

function custom_single_price ($html, $_product)  {

    $from = '<span class="test">' . _x( 'TEST:', 'min_price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' </span>';
    $html = '<del>' . WC_Dynamic_Pricing_Compatibility::wc_price( $base_price ) . '</del><ins> ' . $from . WC_Dynamic_Pricing_Compatibility::wc_price( $display_price ) . '</ins>';

return $html;
}
```